# python: Are there are some class like Voting classifier for three or four regression model

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I want to ensemble　three or four regression model: like GBDT, XGBDT, SVM. I know there are votingC = VotingClassifier() for classifier. I want to know are there some methods or function for ensemble regression model. Now, I just know set the simple weight for each model. how about other good method for ensemble regression model by python. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways in which you could create an ensemble from your base models. Some resources to take a look at are the following:

Firstly, I would point your attention towards [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139042/ensemble-of-different-kinds-of-regressors-using-scikit-learn-or-any-other-pytho), that has a lot of answers and interesting ideas.

*Regarding implementation*:

I have used in the past the [brew](https://github.com/viisar/brew) module that has extensive implementations of different stacking-blending techniques etc, while using different combination rules and diversity metrics. It is also compatible with sklearn models.

Another interesting project is [xcessiv](https://github.com/reiinakano/xcessiv), which I haven't used myself but provides a helpful gui for managing your ensemble's details.

Finally, *regarding theoretical details*, I would suggest you take a look into [this survey](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/~eder/Artigos/Wather/Moreira_2007.pdf) that focuses on ensembles in regression tasks.